# How to convert this small PHP code to Python

Tags: php, python, python-3.x

I have the following PHP function:

```
function x($t, $k) {
    $c = strlen($k);
    $l = strlen($t);
    $o = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < $l;) {
        for ($j = 0; ($j < $c && $i < $l); $j++, $i++) {
              $o.=$t{$i}^$k{$j};
            }
    }
    return $o;
}
```

I need it on Python 3, the second loop is one I am stuck at:

```
def x(t, k):
    c = len(k)
    l = len(t)
    o = ""
    for i in range(0, l):
        # ??
```

Comment: It would be nice to include a description of what it does in PHP, so those like myself that know python but not PHP could make sense of it

Comment: @Reedinationer Sure, in short: function x() is a custom XOR encryption (the first formal parameter is data, and second one is key). The loop doesn't really have an explanation other than self-explanatory, since it is a custom scheme.

Comment: So an expected input may be `(000001000000,000010000000)` with output `000011000000`? You should include details like expected input/output in your post

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
from operator import xor


def x(t, k):
    c = len(k)
    l = len(t)
    o = ''

    for i in range(l):
        j=0
        while((j<c) and  (i<l)):
            #If you really want to do XOR operation 
            o += '1' if xor(bool(t[i]), bool(k[j])) else '0'
            j+=1
            i+=1

    return o
```